# Can a script tag get an EJS variable?

Tags: node.js, maps, ejs

I'm building an app with a NodeJS backend and EJS. I want to create a map with some markers. Those markers are some names of cities and countries from database. My question is: can I somehow use that EJS <%= %> into a script tag ? I did something, but my IDE throws me an error. And if It's possible can you please show me how?

Here are my functions:

NODE JS

```
exports.getMap =  (req,res,next) => {

    const notename = req.params.notename;
  Note.findOne({notename:notename}).then(note => {

    res.render('feed/map', {
        pageTitle:'Pedigree Notes | MAP',
        path:'/getmap',
        locations:note.locations

      });
  })


}
```

AND THE CLIENT SIDE

```
<%- include('../includes/head.ejs'); %>
<%- include('../includes/navigation.ejs');%>

<main>
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div id="map">

    </div>
</div>

<script>
var map;
var geocoder;
function initMap(){
   var mapLayer = document.getElementById('map')
   var centerCoordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(40.4637, 3.7492);
   var defaultOptions = { center:centerCoordinates, zoom:2};

   map = new google.maps.Map(mapLayer,defaultOptions);
   geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
   <% for(let location of locations) { %>
   <% } %>

}
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC8QqwujgKgEaAk2_MvUph9Jows_P1eILs&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
</main>

<%- include('../includes/end.ejs'); %>
```

How can I wrote that for to reach the values parsed from backend?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a template loop - it will only loop on the server, and produce multiplied JS code, which is not what you want. Use this pattern:

```
const locations = <%- JSON.stringify(locations) %>;
```

and then you have a proper JS object on the clientside:

```
locations.forEach(location => {
    ...
});
```

(or an equivalent `for` loop if you insist :P )

Comment: My IDE still 'red' that line, but it's only visual, it is working, thank you very much! In 6 minutes I'll accept the answer!

Comment: If your IDE is checking JS syntax, that is normal - this is EJS.